# WPF Button content binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am sure the solution to this problem is obvious but I simply can't figure it out. I tried every answer I could find on SO with no hope.

**Problem**

I have a simple WPF form that holds a button. The button's text is defined by a view model that changes the text content on click. For the sake of completeness, below is my xaml and the view model laying behind.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:MyVm"
        Height="163.762" Width="201.758" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vms:MyVm />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Button Name="Action" Content="{Binding Path=NextAction, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0" MinHeight="50" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Click="Action_Click"></Button>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyVm: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _nextAction = "START";
    public String NextAction {
        get { return _nextAction; }
        set
        {
            _nextAction = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NextAction");
        }

    }

    public void ExecuteAction()
    {
        if (_nextAction == "START")
            NextAction = "STOP";

        if (_nextAction == "STOP")
            NextAction = "START";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Question**

When I click on the button, I want the text to change from "START" to "STOP" and  vice versa.

- The logic in the view model seem to work fine.
- The `OnPropertyChanged` is correctly called.
- The `handler` inside `OnPropertyChanged` is not `null`

Clicking the button has no effect on the UI. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following logic is incorrect...

```
public void ExecuteAction()
    {
        if (_nextAction == "START")
            NextAction = "STOP";

        if (_nextAction == "STOP")
            NextAction = "START";
    }
```

It should be...

```
public void ExecuteAction()
    {
        if (_nextAction == "START") {
            NextAction = "STOP";
        } else {
            NextAction = "START";
        }
    }
```

You are changing the next action to stop then the following lines of code are changing it back again immediately.