# Change button content MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button with the following content:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <TextBlock Text="Connect"/>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Arrow"/>
  </StackPanel>
```

I searched and found this: [WPF Button content binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055700/wpf-button-content-binding) but I'm not sure how to apply the solution when I have all of the three: a Stackpanel, the PackIcon (object) and the Textblock.

I have this progressBar which I make it appear under the button:

```
 <ProgressBar  x:Name="XZ" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"
                  Visibility="{Binding Connecting, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Value="50"
            IsIndeterminate="True" />
```

I want to make it so when I click the button, instead of showing the ProgressBar where it is right now, to basically remove the Text and the PackIcon and place the ProgressBar in the button.

Comment: Use a data trigger.

Comment: Often a better idea to put a low opacity panel over everything and show a spinner/busy/throbber in that. Take focus when you do. That way it stops the user clicking anything when it's likely to break stuff and it makes it totally clear they're not supposed to just carry on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually changing in the controls could be done with Data Triggers; though that seems a bit over the top in this case.

I would just toggle the visibility of two controls:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding Connecting, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToCollapsedConverter}}"">

                <TextBlock Text="Connect"/>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Arrow"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ProgressBar  x:Name="XZ" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"
                  Visibility="{Binding Connecting, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
            Value="50"
            IsIndeterminate="True" />
</Grid>
```

That would be the content of your button. `BooleanToCollapsedConverter` is just the inverse of a VisibiltyToBooleanConverter; there are a number of ways to do it and is left as an exercise.

As an aside; `UpdateSourceTrigger` doesn't make any sense on a OneWay binding (it doesn't update the source!) and you don't even need that on visibility as that's not an input the user can change.

Comment: So you're suggesting I just hide the controls and show the ProgressBar? I'm not sure how I didn't think about this earlier, I feel stupid. I appreciate it man! thanks

Comment: @BradleyDotNet, may I ask why you would use a `trigger` over a `DataTemplate`

Comment: @3xGuy A data template won't let you switch on a flag; at most on a type. The system you set up with extra classes like that seems even more excessive than a trigger.

Comment: @BradleyDotNet so what I'm reading is that what i did isn't incorrect, Its just a bit of overkill?

Comment: @3xGuy In my opinion; yes that seems like overkill. Extending out your concept means you have classes for every possible state of a UI control in your program. It would be very hard to manage very quickly. What I did or a DataTrigger seems to be the right answer to me

Comment: @BradleyDotNet, Thank you, as I answer on here to get better and try to compare my answers to others. Thank you for your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a data template. Something like:
XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ButtonInfo}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Press me"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Label}"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProgressInfo}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ProgressBar Height="30" Value="{Binding Progress}"></ProgressBar>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Label}"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


   <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding ProcessCommand}" Content="{Binding ButtonInfo}">            
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

C#:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ButtonInfo = new ButtonInfo(){Label = "Button Info"};
        ProcessCommand = new DelegateCommand(Process);
    }
    private ButtonInfo _buttonInfo;
    public ButtonInfo ButtonInfo
    {
        get { return _buttonInfo; }
        set
        {
            _buttonInfo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand ProcessCommand { get; set; }

    private async void Process()
    {
        ButtonInfo = new ProgressInfo(){Label = "Progress Info"};
        await ProcessAsync();
    }

    private Task ProcessAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    ButtonInfo.Progress = i;
                    if (i==99)
                    {
                        ButtonInfo = new ButtonInfo(){Label = "Button Again"};
                    }
                });
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class ButtonInfo:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _label;
    private int _progress;
    private bool _isProcessing;

    public string Label
    {
        get { return _label; }
        set
        {
            _label = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set
        {
            _progress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool IsProcessing
    {
        get { return _isProcessing; }
        set
        {
            _isProcessing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class ProgressInfo : ButtonInfo { }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a template for the button to achieve this, then reuse the template everywhere you want a button with loading as following:

```
    <Button Width="120" Height="40" Tag="False" Name="loadingButton" Click="loadingButton_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border Name="PART_Border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Background="Transparent">
                <Grid Name="PART_Root">
                    <TextBlock Name="PART_Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Data</TextBlock>
                    <ProgressBar  IsIndeterminate="True"  Name="PART_Loading"></ProgressBar>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Text" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Loading" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="False" >
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Text" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_Loading" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

And the event for button click would be:

```
    private async void loadingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        loadingButton.Tag = true.ToString();//display loading
        await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(4000); });//fake data loading
        loadingButton.Tag = false.ToString();//hide loading
    }
```

Note that you can also bind the Tag property for a property inside your view model if you where using MVVM pattern.

Comment: Seems like a DataTrigger would be better than abusing Tag like this

Comment: It seems reasonable to use a template like this, but I would think Tag wouldn't be the best attribute for this. Perhaps a derived user control with an additional property? (called `StatefulButton`, for example?)

Comment: I usually do that creating custom control or at least a user control, but in case the tag was not used it is easier to understand and apply for new people inside WPF

Comment: Maybe isenabled would be an idea.  If this button isn't disabled whilst this process runs then what will happen if the user clicks it again?  Usually that would be something bad.